# Laravel calling a controller function from a model factory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building some tests in my Laravel 5.5 project.

In my GalleryFactory I need to generate a 'link', I have written this code inside a function in my GalleriesController like so;

```
private function generateUrlLink()
{
    $generatedLink = str_random(8);

    $existingGalleryWithGeneratedLink = Gallery::where('link', $generatedLink)->first();

    while (!is_null($existingGalleryWithGeneratedLink)) {
        $generatedLink = str_random(8);
        $existingGalleryWithGeneratedLink = Gallery::where('link', $generatedLink)->first();
    }

    return $generatedLink;
}
```

I don't want to write this code twice in the controller and also the factory as i might want to modify it someday, so im wondering what the best way of going about this would be?

Any help would be fantastic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to write this function in the eloquent model instead of the controller and then calling the function from the model.

```
public static function generateUrlLink()
{
$generatedLink = str_random(8);

$existingGalleryWithGeneratedLink = Gallery::where('link', $generatedLink)->first();

while (!is_null($existingGalleryWithGeneratedLink)) {
    $generatedLink = str_random(8);
    $existingGalleryWithGeneratedLink = Gallery::where('link', $generatedLink)->first();
}

return $generatedLink;
}
```

Hopefully, this works.

Comment: Thank you for that ... How would I go about calling that from a controller or model factory given its a private static function?

Comment: you can always make the function public and then Gallery::generateUrlLink();  assuming Gallery is the class name